# PostgreSQL: Calculate values (e.g. AVG or SUM) over a group of values differentiating by attributes, year and month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with a SQL query and I am pretty sure it can be solved with window functions but I don't get my head around it. So maybe somebody can give me a push in the right direction.

I have a sample table:

| field1 | field2 | year | month | kpi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| someth1 | someth2 | 2020 | 1 | 10.2 |
| someth1 | someth2 | 2020 | 2 | 13.4 |
| someth1 | someth2 | 2020 | 3 | 12.6 |

I made a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=497a1cbb2f1a889bac69d83d7734ed38) to show you better.

I want to add a column (kpi_yr_avg) where the average of the year (of that record) is calculated but only for the actual and the previous months of that year of that data record.

For excample:

| field1 | field2 | year | month | kpi | kpi_yr_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| someth1 | someth2 | 2020 | 1 | 10.2 | 10.2 |
| someth1 | someth2 | 2020 | 2 | 13.4 | 11.8 |
| someth1 | someth2 | 2020 | 3 | 12.7 | 12.1 |

What I mean is:
In january the average is calculated only with the january value.
In february the average is calculated with the january and febraury value.
And so on.

The real table I am working with has different entries in field1 and field 2 and includes months since 2018.

Would be nice if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window function with moving average

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11)
SELECT *
     , AVG(kpi) OVER (PARTITION BY field1, field2, year ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) kpi_yr_avg
FROM test1
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1db8f0f234d0103120876cd95d8f303b

Comment: This works. Thank you very much. Incredible how fast some people can get their head around a problem like this. I really have to learn more about window functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.FIELD1,T.FIELD2,T.YEAR,T.MONTH,T.KPI,
AVG(T.KPI)OVER(PARTITION BY T.FIELD1,T.FIELD2,T.YEAR ORDER BY T.MONTH ASC)AS RUN_AVG 
 FROM test1 AS T ORDER BY T.field1, T.field2, T.year, T.month;
```

Could you please try if the above query is suitable for you

Comment: This works. Thank you very much. Incredible how fast some people can get their head around a problem like this. I really have to learn more about window functions.